# How to restrict a user after 3 consecutive unsuccessful attempts for login in Java Web App?

Tags: java, security, session, spring-mvc, restriction

I want to restrict a user after 3 consecutive unsuccessful attempts to login in my Web Application. Is it possible with only `HttpSession`, without any database operations? I am using Spring MVC, but not using `Spring-Security` for my web application. Please suggest me the way if it is possible.

Comment: Are you planning on using Spring Security?

Comment: no..for this application..its not possible now..:(

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a counter in session how many times user failed to login.
But this will be limited to the browser if user started some other user HttpSession will not work.
You can keep this db after 3rd failure from same browser.
Generally for these kind of task people prefer to maintain in db.

Answer (score 0):

For better approach you need both HttpSession and Database. Example : Accounts can be locked after 3 unsuccessful attempts for a period of 12 hours. After 12 hours again if there is a unsuccessful attempts , the locking period would be 24 hours (or so..increasing time), so you need login table to store these artifacts.

There is a good library called  [ESAPI](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Enterprise_Security_API)  from OWASP, just check it. It has mostly interfaces which allows you to implement but there is a reference implementation just explore it.

```
    incrementFailedLoginCount();
    if (getFailedLoginCount() >= ESAPI.securityConfiguration().getAllowedLoginAttempts()) {
                            lock();
                    }
    throw new AuthenticationLoginException("Login failed", "Incorrect password provided for " + getAccountName() );
```